# How to redirect from the server in axios using a rendered page

Tags: reactjs, render, axios

l am making a request like that

```
axios.get(`api/projects/${id}`)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    dispatch({
      type: ActionTypes.ERROR,
      error: response.data
    });
  });
```

resposne function on server

```
export function getProject(req, res) {
 const projectId = req.params.project_id;
 Project.findById(projectId)
.populate('user', 'username')
.exec((err, project) => { 
  if (err || !project) {
    get404(html => res.send(html));
    return ;
  } 
  else {
    return res.json(project);
  }
});
}
```

`get404` is a function which return the 404 html on server

what l want to do is once `get404` triggered, it should return the 404 page,bu now it returns the whole html page to `resposne.data`. Anyone gives some suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you do `res.send(404);` then you'll get a rejected promise on the client. You can catch it and re-route your client to something like `/404` on the client side.

Comment: thanks for reply, but in my case i don't have a static 404 page on client side. the `get404` generate a dynamic 404 page on server side, is there anyway can redirect to the page in `getProject` once error accurs?

Comment: If you catch a rejected promise, you can just do `window.location = "http://www.yourserver.com/404";` to redirect the browser. Would that work? Then your `/404` handler on the server will read the appropriate 404 file and return it.

Comment: yeah,it works!Thank you! But can you please explain to me why it can find the `get404`  generated page :)

Comment: When you use `axios` or any `ajax` call in JavaScript, the response comes back as data. If you send back content of an HTML file, what you get is a long string of the content of that file. Since it's within the context of the ajax, the browser won't render it. But if the _browser_ makes the HTTP request, then it will try to render the returned content. Does that make sense?

Comment: The distinction is one is called from JS and the other is made by the browser.

Comment: emmm,thanks.But what still confused me is `http://www.yourserver.com/404` can't match any api, how can it find the appropriate 404 page which l coded, but not the default page maybe?

Comment: That depends on what handler you have on the server. If you can include those I might be able to help.

Comment: l think l understand! Thank you very much!